# How can I resume installation of a package from ports?

Tags: port, openbsd, reinstall

I have a virtual machine in VMWare Workstation 7.0 with OpenBSD 4.4 and I was installing some ports. Most of them were installed correctly but not two. I had to cancel them because the system didn't respond and the installation wasn't at 100%. One of these ports is ***dbus***.

Now, I want to reinstall these ports, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right answer to that question is deleting the partial package first and then install it again. How you can do that??? In [section 15 of OpenBSD FAQ](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq15.html) explain that is better to eliminate the partial package first and then install it.

```
$pkg_info -a # List all packages installed.

partial-cups # Partial packages appear with partial word first.

$pkg_delete partial-cups # This command eliminate the patial cups package.

$pkg_add cups # At last, install the package again.
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry about whether the package was already partially installed since it will re-install over the same locations.

The only precaution you might want to take is to ensure that any cruft from the previous compile is tidied up before you start again. So use the command:

```
make clean install
```

Comment: Sorry, I try to execute this command (to the package) but it's not what I need. The packages I cancelled appear in pkg_info as "partial_package name" so I thing there is a command to reinstall or continue with the installation.